# Validation loss being lower than the training loss and it does not decrease in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I was trying to train a image to image translation model using transunet. I split my data by 70%, 15%, 15% for training, validation and testing. But when I monitor the loss curve, I find that the validation loss is much lower than the training loss.

**loss curve:**
[image: loss_curve_image]

The code is here:

```py
criterion = nn.L1Loss()
net = net.cuda()
net = torch.nn.DataParallel(net, device_ids=range(torch.cuda.device_count()))
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=lr, betas=(0.9, 0.999))
scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer, mode='min', patience=3)

for epoch in range(1, total_epoch + 1):
    print('---------- Epoch:'+str(epoch)+ ' ----------')
    # data_loader_iter = iter(data_loader)
    data_loader_iter = data_loader
    train_epoch_loss = 0.
    print('Train:')
    for img, mask in tqdm(data_loader_iter,ncols=20,total=len(data_loader_iter)):
        net.train()
        img, mask = img.to(device), mask.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        pred = net(img)
        train_loss = criterion(pred, mask)
        train_epoch_loss += train_loss
        train_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    train_epoch_loss /= len(data_loader_iter)
    val_data_loader_num = val_data_loader
    test_data_loader_num = test_data_loader

    val_epoch_loss = 0
    test_epoch_loss = 0

    #Validation
    print('Validation:')
    with torch.no_grad():
        for val_img, val_mask in tqdm(val_data_loader_num,ncols=20,total=len(val_data_loader_num)):
            val_img, val_mask = val_img.to(device), val_mask.to(device)
            net.eval()
            predict = net(val_img)
            val_loss = criterion(predict, val_mask)
            val_epoch_loss += val_loss
    val_epoch_loss = val_epoch_loss / len(val_data_loader_num)
```

Another problem is that, when I was testing the model, one class could not be predicted properly, that class is always clustered at the edge of the image， see the green class in the figure below:

[image: test_image_prediction]

while the ground truth looks like this:

[image: ground_truth]

I know there seems to be to many problems, but anyone has faced similar problems? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you fix the indentation? The line after the for loop.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation at the second for loop?

Comment: Fixed that, sorry that I am not so familiar with the code format in stackoverflow.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.